# how to fix terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Tags: c++

I am not sure what is causing this problem, I am creating a tic tac toe game where you play against the computer.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what this error means.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void InitializeBoard(int *gameBoard);
void InitializeTurns(int &whosturnisit,int &turnsTaken);
void InitializegameBoard (int *gameBoard);
void DrawScreen (int *gameBoard);
void taketurnplayer(int *gameBoard,int &turnsTaken,int &whosturnisit);
void taketurncomputer(int *gameBoard,int turnsTaken,int whosturnisit);
int checkforwinner(int *gameBoard);
void displayWinner (int &whoWins);


int main()
{
int gameBoard[10];
int whosturnisit, turnsTaken, whoWins;

    InitializeTurns(whosturnisit,turnsTaken);
    InitializegameBoard(gameBoard);
    DrawScreen (gameBoard);

    do
        {
        if (whosturnisit==1)
            taketurnplayer(gameBoard,turnsTaken,whosturnisit);
        else
            taketurncomputer(gameBoard,turnsTaken,whosturnisit);
        DrawScreen(gameBoard);
        whoWins=checkforwinner(gameBoard);
        }while (  (turnsTaken<9) && (whoWins==0) );
    displayWinner(whoWins);
    return 99;
}

void InitializegameBoard (int *gameBoard)
{
    for (int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    gameBoard[i]=0;
return;
}

void InitializeTurns(int &whosturnisit, int &turnsTaken)
{
    string i=0;
    whosturnisit=0;
    turnsTaken=0;
    cin>>i;
    if (i=="yes")
        whosturnisit=1;
    else
        whosturnisit=2;
return;
}

void DrawScreen(int *gameBoard)
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i=1;i<11;i++)
    cout<<gameBoard[i];
return;
}

void taketurnplayer(int *gameBoard,int &turnsTaken,int &whosturnisit)
{
    int x=0;
    do
    {
    cout<<"where would u like to place your x";
    cin>>x;
    }while (gameBoard[x]!=0);
    gameBoard[x]=1;
    whosturnisit=2;
    turnsTaken++;
    return;
}
void taketurncomputer(int*gameBoard, int turnsTaken, int whosturnisit)
{
    int spot=0;
    do
    {
        spot=1+(std::rand()%(9-1+1));
    }while (gameBoard[spot]!=0);
    gameBoard[spot]=2;
    whosturnisit=1;
    turnsTaken++;
    return;
}
checkforwinner (int*gameBoard)
{
    int thewinneris=0;
    if((gameBoard[1]==gameBoard[2])&&(gameBoard[2]==gameBoard[3])&&(gameBoard[3]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[1];
    else if ((gameBoard[4]==gameBoard[5])&&(gameBoard[5]==gameBoard[6])&&(gameBoard[6]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[4];
    else if ((gameBoard[7]==gameBoard[8])&&(gameBoard[8]==gameBoard[9])&&(gameBoard[9]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[7];
    else if ((gameBoard[1]==gameBoard[5])&&(gameBoard[5]==gameBoard[9])&&(gameBoard[9]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[1];
    else if ((gameBoard[2]==gameBoard[5])&&(gameBoard[5]==gameBoard[8])&&(gameBoard[8]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[2];
    else if ((gameBoard[1]==gameBoard[4])&&(gameBoard[4]==gameBoard[7])&&(gameBoard[7]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[1];
    else if ((gameBoard[3]==gameBoard[6])&&(gameBoard[6]==gameBoard[9])&&(gameBoard[9]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[3];
    else if ((gameBoard[3]==gameBoard[5])&&(gameBoard[5]==gameBoard[7])&&(gameBoard[7]!=0))
        thewinneris=gameBoard[3];
        return thewinneris;
}
void displayWinner(int &whoWins)
{
    cout<<whoWins;
}
```

the visual stuff is not done but the program should be able to run now I think. The error I keep recieving from the terminal is :

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 0.884 s
Press any key to continue.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: `string i=0;` is wrong. It tries to initialize `std::string` using `NULL` pointer, which is illegal. Just don't initialize it, you will overwrite anything with user input anyway: `std::string i;`

Comment: thanks that worked. All good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Change

```
std::string i = 0;
```

and friends to

```
std::string i;
```

This will produce empty strings. While you are at it, consider giving the string a meaningful identifier like `input` or `yes_no`. This will likely help a lot when debugging later and descriptive code greatly reduces the need for comments.

## The problem:

```
std::string i = 0;
```

and friends.

## Why it is a problem:

This is an initialization so a constructor is called.

`std::string` doesn't have a constructor that can convert an integer, but it does have a constructor that will take a pointer to a character array and unfortunately an integer literal of 0 looks enough like the old definition of a `NULL` pointer

```
#define NULL 0
```

to call it rather than emit a compiler error.

Constructing a `std::string` with a NULL pointer is pretty much instantly fatal, so the `string` constructor traps it and throws an exception.

```
std::string i = 1;
```

does not have this problem. The compiler instantly rejects it because there is no historical equivalency between 1 and a pointer or anything else that can be used to initialize a `string`.

## Side note:

Later in the code watch out for `checkforwinner (int*gameBoard)`. It looks like the return type is missing. You'll need to fix this because the program is not running as expected.

There could be a compiler warning for that. If there is, don't ignore warnings. They are the first line of defense against logic errors, so if anything you want to see MORE warnings so that you can fix them before they become harder-to-diagnose runtime problems. Check your compiler documentation for how to turn up the warning level and then crank it up **LOUD!**

Comment: thanks you for all the information, i fixed all of those and its up and running thank you so much!